# invalid read of size 8 using Valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind

When I run my program with valgrind it gives an invalid read and write of size 8 error. I have broke my head over this but I can't see what's going wrong.

The valgrind errors occur in the last and second last lines of this code:

```
void MLPerceptron::returnOutputActivation(vector<Feature> imageFeatures,vector<double>& outputActivation){
    int train = 1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<imageFeatures.size();i++){
        activations[0] = imageFeatures[i].content;
        feedforward(train);
        activationsToOutputProbabilities();
        setMinActivation(outputActivation,activations[2]);
    }
}

void MLPerceptron::setMinActivation(vector<double>& minOutputActivation,vector<double> currentActivation){

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<currentActivation.size();i++){
            if(minOutputActivation[i] > currentActivation[i])
                    minOutputActivation[i] = currentActivation[i];
    }
}
```

The vectors are initialized in another function and then given to the function returnOutputActivations, this happens in a different file see here:

```
void MLPController:: createOutputProbabilitiesVectorTest(vector<vector<Feature> >& testSet){
    unsigned int nOutputProbabilities = settings.mlpSettings.nOutputUnits;

    vector<double> input;
    input.reserve(nOutputProbabilities*nMLPs);

    for(int j=0; j<nMLPs; j++){
        vector<Feature>::const_iterator first = testSet[j].begin();
        vector<Feature>::const_iterator last = testSet[j].begin()+numPatchesPerSquare[j];

        vector<double> inputTemp = vector<double>(nOutputProbabilities, 10.0);

        mlps[0][j].returnOutputActivation(vector<Feature>(first,last),inputTemp);

        input.insert(input.end(),inputTemp.begin(),inputTemp.end());    
    }

    Feature newFeat = new Feature(input);   
    newFeat.setLabelId(testSet[0][0].getLabelId());
    inputTrainSecondLayerMLP.push_back(newFeat);
}
```

I know that there already a lot of posts about the valgrind error but it didn't help me to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ask us help for debugging.

Comment: `imageFeatures.size());` will emit compile error due to an extra `)`.

Comment: `Feature newFeat = new Feature(input);` this may be valid but smells. Why not `Feature newFeat(input);` nor `Feature* newFeat = new Feature(input);`?

Answer (score 0):

I think
    `Feature newFeat = new Feature(input)`
is the problem. This will allocate a new Feature on the heap, but you will lose its address and it will thus not be deleted. Use `Feature* newFeat = new Feature(input)` as per MikeCAT's suggestion.